# Running python in QwikLabs Linux VM through Windows PuTTY doesn't work but through mac it does. Is there a way to make it work on Windows?

Tags: python, virtual-machine

I'm taking this course which requires us to ssh into a Qwiklabs Linux VM and write a python script to manipulate files and stuff on the VM. When I try ssh using PuTTY in windows 10, everything goes fine up to the point I have to run the script, then it returns invalid syntax errors. As far as I know, nothing is wrong with the code. The images linked will also show that the syntaxerrors point to stuff like valid variable names and even colons after for loops. I tested the code by trying to ssh into the VM through a mac and the script worked. Is there any way to fix this and make it run on Windows? Switching back and forth between computers is less than ideal for me and I also find it really intriguing because as far as I'm aware, it shouldn't matter which platform I'm connecting to the VM from because the python script is running on the VM. Hope someone can help, I'm a beginner and am really new to coding and ssh.[python error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYgu1.png). [Another python error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDUim.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the VM. It is a problem with the code. From what I see in your error there is probably a unclosed parentheses above that line causing it to fail. I would need to see the code for more information.